# Why does using css calc function to calculate complex expression doesn' work?

Tags: css

I want to use css calc to calculate the widh , but it doesn't work.

```
.box {
  width: calc(1235px * (100vh / 375px * 667px / 100vw));
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Please have a look at https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ and update your question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: A little bit of research would've helped you find out that in `calc`'s division the right side must be a number ( not a unit ) and in the multiplication at least one ( left or right ) must be a number.